# Can I prove the order limit theorem with a counter example?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In [this mathematical text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn7WT.png) they are giving a proof for the first statement using a proof by contradiction that I perfectly understand, but I just don't understand why they did not just give this counterexample:
$a_n = \frac{1}{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}$

This sequence has the property that all of its elements are greater than zero, and it converges to 0. Since 0 is not less than zero, we get a contradiction.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counterexample is not a counterexample. The statement in question says the following:

> Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. Then, if $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$, then $a\geq 0$.

Your example merely shows that there exists **some** sequence $a_n$ such that all its values are positive, and the limit is $0$. The existence of one such sequence does nothing to prove the original statement. It is also not in conflict with the original statement, but it does not *prove* the original statement.

Also, note that the mere existence of **any** single sequence can never be proof enough of the original statement. This is because the original statement is talking about **all** sequences with a given property.

Comment: If I understand right, my counterexample would be a counterexample if the negation of the original statement were " for all the sequences with the given property we have a < 0". Right?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Your counterexample is just what you need to show the converse of the statement is false.

Comment: @ShinobiSan Correct.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n >0 ,\space \space \forall n>N $ and $a_n \to a $ $\implies a\ge 0$

Proof: Suppose, $a<0$

Then, $a< \frac{a}{2} <0$

Given, $a_n \to a$.

Then the interval $(\frac{3a}{2},\frac{a}{2})$ contains all but finitely many terms of $(a_n).$

This contradict the hypothesis that $a_n>0 \space \space \forall n>N$ .

In your case, $\frac{1}{n} >0$

And, $\lim (\frac{1}{n})=0\ge 0$

So, it is an example and doesn't contradict our statment.